# Make braces more visible in VS Code

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for all web development, but I find it hard to see the braces when working with Angular 2 bindings. Braces are light gray and very thin in the Dark+ theme.

```
hideCancelButton [{ngModel}]="subredditValue"
```

I would like to color the curly and square brackets or make them bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this extension [Subtle Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafamel.subtle-brackets#overview)  by modifying the following the default values in the .json settings of VS Code:

I changed it like this:

```
"subtleBrackets.bracketPairs": [
    "{}",
    "[]",
    "()",
    "<>"
],
"subtleBrackets.styles": {
    "global": {
        "color": "yellow",
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderStyle": "none none solid none"
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set to "false" the value of .matchbrackets of VS Code.

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks for sharing. Funny 10 minutes later I am reading this https://programmingwithmosh.com/angular/essential-vscode-extensions-for-angular-developers/

Comment: Welcome Martin.:)

Answer (score 1):

The bracket colors aren't defined by the color themes. Since Version 1.60 from August 2021 VS Code provides native support for bracket pair colorization. This feature also sets the colors for brackets in general, even if you don't use the bracket-pair feature.

Therefore to change the desired colors for brackets add or modify the following entry in `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`:

```
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
    "Gold",
    "Orchid",
    "LightSkyBlue"
]
```

Changing "Gold" to e.g. "Orange" should solve the issue as shown in the example images below:

[image: default colors]

-----------^ Here in row 27 you can see that the color of the curly bracket changed from "Gold"

[image: modified colors]

-----------^ to "Orange".

The change will also impact HTML comment tags `<!-- -->` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a your own customized theme or try one of the themes available on the Marketplace

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/themes